# How to upgrade Ubuntu from 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, macbook

I’m unable to figure out how to upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10. I have tried searching for the update and I can never see it as my software is apparently up to date, I need it to be able to use my keyboard and trackpad on my MacBook.

Alternatively if anyone has a solution to enable the trackpad and keyboard that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've googled your question and found [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseNotes?action=show&redirect=19.10%2FReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_19.04):

> ## Upgrading from Ubuntu 19.04
>
> To upgrade on a desktop system:
>
> - Open the *Software & Updates* application.
> - Select the 3rd Tab called *Updates*.
> - Set the *Notify me of a new Ubuntu version* dropdown menu to *For any new version*.
> - Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type in `update-manager -c -d` into the command box.
> - Update Manager should open up and tell you: *New distribution release '19.10' is available.*
>
>   - If not you can also use `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk`
> - Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions.

(formatting edited for SuperUser)

Comment: Perfect, yeah I tried the first thing and it didn’t work. That line at the end though did